# Accessing Single Entries in Sparse Matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to use sparse matrices for BOW feature representation. I have experimented with coo_matrix from scipy, but it doesn't seem to support what I want to do:

I would like to initialize a matrix of all zeros and then change a given entry to one when appropriate. But when I try to index the matrix how I think I should -- myMatrix[0][0] = 1 (or even myMatrix[0][0][0] =1), for example -- it changes all the values in a row to 1. I want to just make a single entry 1.

I can do this easily with numpy matrices, but I would like to use sparse matrices for space efficiency.

Comment: Try `myMatrix[0, 0] = 1`, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. But you have to have .todense() when you initialize the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Using the right `sparse` type helps.

```
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.lil_matrix((10,10))
M[1,1] = 1
M[5,5] = 1
# <10x10 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

`dok` also works.  `csr` suggests using `lil`. 'coo' can't be set this way. Once filled it is easy to convert to another format.

Comment: I think `dok` would be more efficient for random access